# limit outputs by awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to get the results for an exact column, that are greater than `0`, and less that `10,000,000`.

The file I has as following:

```
799,799,0,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,5155,5155,,0.000000
673,273,0,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,5155,5155,,0.000000
941,741,0,0,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5157,5157,,9999998.140000
```

The last column could include any value between `0.000000` and `10,000,000`.

I need the outputs to be restricted to to the values more than `0`, and less than `10,000,000`.

I tried the following command:

```
awk -F"," '$21<"10000000"' | awk -F"," '$21>"0.000000"'
```

but the outputs of $21 are always 1000.000000

Below a sample of the outputs:

```
647,790,1,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,5155,5155,,1000.000000
600,796,1,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,5300,5300,,1000.000000
950,797,1,0,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,5300,5300,,1000.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$21<"10000000"` make `awk` used string comparison instead of number comparison.

Try:

```
awk -F, '$NF>0 && $NF<10000000' <file
```

Using `$NF` always give you the last field, you can add or remove others field independently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
gawk -F"," "$21<10000000 && $21 > 0" a
```

with this output:

```
941,741,0,0,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5157,5157,,9999998.140000
```

I do not understand how your awk is generating the 1000.000000 values, nor how it is able to compare numbers to strings (you quoted the ten million and zero values in your conditions).  What system are you using?